# find IP addresses not in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of /24 IP addresses in an array called *subRet*

subRet's values are like
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.50
10.0.0.80

What I want is a list of IP address that are NOT in the array.

What I've tried is this:

```
 var test=['10.0.0.1','10.0.0.103','10.0.0.111','10.0.0.131','10.0.0.198'];
 for(i=1;i<=254;i++){
            if( ! $.inArray('10.0.0.'+i.toString(), test ) ) {
                console.log("adding "+'10.0.0.'+i.toString());
            }
  }
```

Console log says

```
adding 10.0.0.1
```

What I want is a list if IP's that are not in the list, like 10.0.0.2.

how?

Comment: First I'd put the array's values into a set/object/etc so you don't have to iterate the array each time. Then just check if it's in the set/object/etc. I see zero value in using jQuery for this.

Comment: I used used test.includes instead and that seems to work, thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind that `includes` will iterate over the `test` array for every value you pass in. It likely doesn't *matter*,  but IMO using a set/etc. is cleaner, and communicates the intent better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this worked

```
    var test=['10.0.0.1','10.0.0.103','10.0.0.111','10.0.0.131','10.0.0.198'];
    for(i=1;i<=254;i++){
            if( ! test.includes('10.0.0.'+i.toString()) ) {
                console.log("adding "+'10.0.0.'+i.toString());
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not declaring the variable `i` anywhere, which is bad practice as the scope will likely not be what you expect. Secondly, no need for jQuery here, you can use vanilla ES6. Third, no need to call `i.toString` as you're concatenating it to a string already, which performs implicit casting.

```
var test=['10.0.0.1','10.0.0.103','10.0.0.111','10.0.0.131','10.0.0.198'];
for(let i = 1; i <= 254; i++){
   if(!test.includes('10.0.0.' + i)) {
       console.log("adding 10.0.0." + i);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm declaring i... I just didn't it in my sample.

Comment: If you're declaring it outside the for loop, the value you get in the console log might not be the actual value for the iteration you're on, since it'll be in a different scope and console logs can be asynchronous. Declaring it in the loop with `let` forces it to be block scoped to the loop body, which gives the result you're expecting.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk console logs cannot be asynchronous (unless called from a worker). it's not necessary to use "let" here (although i do agree that it's good practice, if all target browsers support it)

Comment: @obe It can be synchronous, asynchronous, or synchronous-but-delayed, depending on implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/2444210

Comment: @IceMetalPunk ok, i'll rephrase. console.log() is not asynchronous for all intents and purposes. can you find one example for a browser or debug tool (that people actually use) that implements console.log() in such a way that it would not be reliable in the above example? (and, also, how would using `let` make it any less asynchronous..?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your code is in the way you check the result of the method `inArray`, since `inArray` method retrieves the index of the tested IP in the array, and when it finds nothing it returns -1. So you need to make sure that the returned index is higher than -1:

```
 if( ! $.inArray('10.0.0.'+i.toString(), test ) > -1)
```

[Read more about inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)